# How to navigate to a URL while respecting Ctrl-click opens URL in new tab?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I'd like to be able to (from Javascript) navigate as though a link had been clicked (but not necessarily when a link is clicked -- could be another action).

I know `window.location.href = '...';` and `window.location.replace('...');`, but these methods don't allow the user to specify new window, new tab, etc. by holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.  I'd like to be able to do it without manually checking the states of these keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to handle both clicks, normal and ctrl-click this is what I use :

```
$("li").on("click", function(e){
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        $('<a href="'+ url + '" target="_blank"></a>')[0].click();
    } else {
        document.location = url;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Any way to not open this in the foreground?

Answer (score 4):

This only works if you do it from a click handler triggered by the user, otherwise, the browser will detect it as an unwanted pop up and block it:

```
<div id="test">open in new tab</div>

$('#test').click(function(){    
    openInNewTab('http://example.com');
});

function openInNewTab(url)
{
    $('<a href="'+ url + '" target="_blank">open in new tab</a>')[0].click();
}
```

I think there is no other option since this is a security behavior.

Comment: It's not ideal, but I'll take it.